# Visual Studio Code - apply rename file refactoring in all ES6 imports

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I've typescript application build with ES6 modules.

How do I rename ts or js file representing a module without breaking ES6 import that referenced the renamed file?

e.g:
rename `MyModule.ts` to `RenamedModule.ts` -> change `import * from './MyModule'` to `import * from  './RenamedModule'` in all files;

*Is there an VSCode extension or typescript service that would rename module path in all ES6 imports when renaming file?*

**EDIT:**

[vote for this vscode feature on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21075)

Comment: who marked this as off topic?  I believe this is perfectly within scope:
•software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
•a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vscode nows supports this feature.  It's strange, when I did a file rename on a js file, it didn't work.

However, when I did a drag and drop of a file, vscode put up a dialog asking me if it should update all the paths for me.  There's an option to have it always do it, which I selected.

After that I tried doing the file rename again on a js file, and it refactored all of my paths.  I'm curious to know if others had the same experience as I did.

Comment: This feature of vscode is buggy as hell. The workaround you suggested only works sometimes. Did you find a solution, maybe an extension?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issues, I set `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` to `always` and it doesn't work if I move files from one directory to another...

Comment: I just dragged a folder with files a few days ago and it refactored all my paths.  This was for an angular 2+ project which uses typescript.

Answer (score 8):

I was just looking for the same thing and found this VSCode extension:

[move-ts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts)

It is very young, but seems to be under active development. I tested it on my Windows machine and immediately ran into an issue with backslashes being used. There is, however, already a pull request to fix this (not by me).
As soon as this is fixed, I think this might be what you (we) are looking for.
**EDIT: As of 2017-May-11, the windows issue is fixed.**

There is an ongoing discussion for a "refactor move file" suggestion for Typescript itself [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6487), but it seems to be very early stage.
It seems, until this is built, this functionality is unlikely to be included in VSCode itself, as this [open ticket for VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19439) explains, which tracks the main feature request you linked to in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin there called "rename"
It can be downloaded under the plugins section of Visual Studio Code.

You can simply use the findRll and replace that comes with most text editors such as NotePad++